# Is the entangled state collapsing in the moment of seperation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

How do we conclude that the following is not the case:

We have two qubits, which are entangled. Now I separate these qubits from each other. At this moment, the entanglement collapses, and both qubits are now in the same state. If Alice measures now again, the result isn't changing - but she thinks that the state collapses right now (during her measurement) and mistakenly concludes that there is something like a simultaneously correspondence between the two qbits.

Comment: No: if the collapse occurs simply due to spatial separation,  you would expect that if you bring them together again, they would no longer be entangled, but that would not match experiment

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing would be a [hidden variable theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory). The problem is that Alice and Bob can each independently rotate their qubit before measuring it, and they will still find a correlation between their outputs (if they repeat the experiment many times) that is higher than can be explained by any form of local hidden variables - this is the essence of [Bell's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem). Experimental validation of Bell's theorem rules out hidden variable theories *unless* we allow some sort of faster-than-light communication between the entangled qubits.

Comment: How does such a rotation look like - can you show this at the example of a bell state

Comment: @nuemlouno Quantum logic gates such as $R_x$, $R_y$ and $R_z$ rotate a single qubit on the surface of the Bloch sphere. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere for more details.

Comment: @ gandalf61 I know of these rotations, but you wrote that they independently rotate their qbits and still find a correlation. This sounds for me like they can infer from a single measurment if this state was entanglet ot not - but this is not the case, right? Only statistic can tell them if it or not?

Comment: @nuemlouno Yes, a statistical correlation between outputs cannot be determined from a single pair of measurements - there need to be multiple experiments.